# Which species can't appear in the rate expression for this reaction scheme?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

> **Question**
>   Which species can't appear in the rate expression for this reaction scheme?
>   Here is the reaction scheme in steps: 
>   \begin{align}
> \ce{A + B~(slow) &\rightarrow C} \\
> \ce{C~(fast) &\rightarrow D + B}\\
> \ce{D + E~(fast) &\rightarrow F}\\
> \ce{F~(fast) &\rightarrow G}\\
> \end{align}

The answers are apparently F and G, but I don't see why D and E couldn't also be valid (considering the first step is the slowest). A and B will inevitably be in the rate equation since they are reactants in the rate determining step. C produces B (alongside D) and so will also be in the rate equation as a result. However, why can't we rule out D and E of being in the rate equation, considering they don't seem to have any effect on the concentrations of A and  B.

Comment: B seems to me like a catalyst, and C is an intermediate.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this question requires assuming that all steps are "elementary", e.g. that $\ce{A + B -> C}$ is an irreversible bimolecular reaction that is first-order in $[\ce{A}]$ and first-order in $[\ce{B}]$.  (Obviously we are also assuming that activities can approximated by concentrations.)

With that assumption, the fact that $\ce{C}$ conversion is "fast" means that we can replace the existence of $\ce{C}$ in the scheme entirely:

\begin{align}
\ce{A + B~(slow) &\rightarrow D + B} \\
\ce{D + E~(fast) &\rightarrow F}\\
\ce{F~(fast) &\rightarrow G}\\
\end{align}

Likewise if $\ce{F}$ conversion is "fast", then it can be replaced:

\begin{align}
\ce{A + B~(slow) &\rightarrow D + B} \\
\ce{D + E~(fast) &\rightarrow G}\\
\end{align}

Hopefully this makes it clear why $\ce{E}$ *must* appear in any rate law for formation of $\ce{G}$: there is no source of it in the two reactions we are left with.

For $\ce{D}$, I agree that the situation is a bit more complex.  It might appear in the rate equation, or it might not.  Necessary reactants at the beginning of the reaction if we are ever to see product $\ce{G}$ are $\ce{A}$, $\ce{B}$, and $\ce{E}$, so it would make sense to eliminate $\ce{D}$ from the rate law if possible.  However, that could be algebraically difficult, or perhaps $\ce{D}$ is easier to measure, etc.  There is no reason $\ce{D}$ *can't* appear in the rate law.

**Huge caveat:** "fast" and "slow" are relative terms and as such without further context they are ambiguous.  The problem as constructed sounds a bit sloppy.  For example, is the "fastness" of $\ce{F -> G}$ faster or less fast than the fastness of $\ce{D + E -> F}$?  The problem doesn't say but the simplifications I did above actually depend on these sorts of details.